# Why does sendmail take one minute - causing 504 gateway timeout

Tags: sendmail, digital-ocean

It seems every time an email is sent from a certain Digitalocean setup, it takes one minute to send. For example, setting this file:

```
Subject: Terminal Email Send

Email Content line 1
Email Content line 2
```

and then running:

```
time sendmail 'myemail@somewhere.com' < /tmp/emailfile
```

will send the email, but it takes one minute - exactly for the command to finish. This is causing 504 gateway timeout errors whenever it emails, for example a Wordpress password reset.

Answer (score 0):

The answer seems to be one more line in /etc/hosts of the server:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost.localdomain localhost hostname-of-the-server
```

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/sendmail-is-slow-to-send-mail